# Allow interaction with view behind depending on UITouch.TouchType using point(inside:with:). (PKCanvasView)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitouch, pencilkit

#### The problem

I am trying to intercept touches on a view using the following logic:

1. Determine whether `UITouch.TouchType` is `.pencil`
2. If not `.pencil`, pass touches through to view below
3. Else if `.pencil`, handle touch. (`UIGestureRecognizer`)

---

#### My attempt

After some research I found that the way to allow a touch to be **handled by the view below** was by using `point(inside:with:)` and returning `false` when this was required.

This was fine if i wanted to use `CGPoint` location to determine the Bool but in my case I need to access the `UITouch` itself.

I tried using the `UIEvent` passed into the function to access the touches associated to that event but that would only return an empty set of `UITouch`.

---

Here is my subclass used to implement this approach:

```
class ThroughTouchesPKCanvasView: PKCanvasView {
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        print("Override point")
        if let event = event{
            print(event.allTouches) //prints: Optional(Set([]))
            return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
        } else {
            return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**So, in summary, How can I pass touches on to a view below depending on whether the user used an apple pencil for the touch?**

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?